# jQuery module not found using jquery-slim package?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, browserify, laravel-elixir

I am using Laravel framework with laravel-elixir, [jquery-slim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-slim), vuejs, vue-resource npm packages.

My issue is that when I try to import a jquery plugin (ex. snackbarjs) its giving me an issue since the jquery module is not being recognised.

**The error:**

```
Browserify Failed!: Cannot find module 'jquery'
```

I know where the problem comes from, the snackbarjs in this case tries to require the jquery plugin using this code:

```js
(function (factory) {
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(['jquery'], factory);
} else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node/CommonJS
    module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
} else {
    // Browser globals
    factory(jQuery);
}
```

My app.js file looks like this:

```js
import $ from 'jquery-slim';
import jQuery from 'jquery-slim';
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import 'snackbarjs';
Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(Vuex);
```

Is there a way for snackbarjs to ignore the 'jquery' module requirement or to change the name of the module to 'jquery' from 'jquery-slim'?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try `import 'jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js'`

you can find more info on [this page](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/webpack/force-jquery-slim-import-in-webpack/)